# Compare and display data Based On Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement where I want to compare data from two tables and display only the columns if they is a mismatch using sql query.

Say userid, email and phone number of the same person are stored in two tables. Now I want to compare the data of email and phone number from both the tables and display email and phone number only if they are different data.

I tried something like this but this does not solve my purpose as it does not match null data and two columns cannot be compared:

```
select email, phone
case when  employee.email != user_details.email then 'Mis-match'
else ' ' end as Email
from employee, user_details
where employee.usrid=user_details.usrid;
```

How can we achieve this, any pointers?

-Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, the result you're trying to get for it, and the actual result this query produces?

Comment: ok, @Mureinik say employee table has three columns: user_id, user_email, user_phone and the data are: (emp001, emp001@xcomp.com, 00200), (emp003, emp002@xcomp.com, 00345).   The table user_details has three columns: user_id, phno, email and the data are: (emp001, 00201, emp001@comp.com), (emp003, 00345,emp00@xcomp.com).  I want to write a query that displays the columns which has different data; 00200, 00201, emp001@xcomp.com, emp001@comp.com and emp002@xcomp.com, emp00@xcomp.com

Comment: It's really hard to read anything like that in comments. Can you edit it into your post please?

Answer (score 0):

If everything you want is to consider null values in 2 tables as matching - you need to update you `case` to something like this:

```
case when ((employee.email is null and user_details.email is null) or
           (employee.email = user_details.email)) then
  ' ' 
else
  'Mis-match'
end as Email
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Well the above query add a separate column to the output. That is something I don't require. I only want to display the columns   compared with the two tables which have different data for the same user. There can be data for one column for one user in one table but the same data can be null in another table.  Any pointers please.

Comment: If you want to restrict rows that are showed to only those users that have different data - you should move the condition to the where clause like `where ... and ((employee.email is null and user_details.email is not null) or (employee.email is not null and user_details.email is null) or (employee.email != user_details.email))`

Comment: The main challenge is the structure of the two tables are not same! Now a user has 36 attributes which has to be compared and displayed only if they are different.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Well this will check if only email is different in the two tables for the same user. What if I also want to check if the employee.user_phone is not equal to user_details.phno is equal for the same user along with email?

Comment: Just stack similar pseudo-columns in the select list and similar conditions in the where clause joined by `OR`. Like `WHERE employee.userid = user_details.userid AND (((employee.email ... ) or ....) OR (employee.user_phone is null and user_details.phno is not null) or (employee.user_phone is not null and user_details.phno is null) or (employee.user_phone != user.details.phno) OR ...)`